# Cluster high dimensional data with python and DBSCAN

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, n-dimensional

I have a dataset with 1000 dimensions and I am trying to cluster the data with DBSCAN in Python. I have a hard time understanding what metric to choose and why.

Can someone explain this? And how should I decide what values to set `eps` to?

I am interested in the finer structure of the data so the `min_value` is set to 2. Now I use the regular metric that is preset for dbscan in sklearn, but for small eps values, such as `eps` < 0.07, I get a few clusters but miss many points and for larger values i get several smaller clusters and one huge. I do understand that everything depends on the data at hand but I am interested in tips on how to choose eps values in a coherent and structured way and what metrics to choose!

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155542/deciding-input-values-to-dbscan-algorithm) and the answers there are with regards to 10 dimensions I have 1000 :) and I also do not know how to evaluate my metric so it would be interesting with a more elaborate explanation then: evaluate your metric!

Edit: Or tips on other clustering algorithms that work on high dimensional data with an existing python implementation.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, with `minPts=2` you aren't actually doing DBSCAN clustering, but the result will **degenerate into single-linkage clustering**.

You really should use `minPts=10` or higher.

Unfortunately, you didn't bother to tell us what distance metric you actually use!

Epsilon really depends heavily on your data set and metric. We cannot help you there without knowing the parameters and your data set. Have you tried plotting a distance histogram to see which values are typical? That probably is the best heuristic to choose this threshold: look at quantiles of the distance histogram (or a sample thereof).

However, note that OPTICS does get rid of this parameter (at least when you have a proper implementation). When extracting clusters with the Xi method, you only need epsilon large enough to not cut structure you are interested in (and small enough to get the runtime you want - larger is slower, although not linearly). Xi then gives a relative increase in distance that is considered to be significant.

Comment: Well I wrote: "I use the regular metric that is preset for dbscan in sklearn" :) I assume the metric is regular euclidean distance! One of the problems here is that I am not well versed in clustering theory so I really do not understand your point very well. OPTICS doesn't seem to be implemented in python so it's not my first choice.

What are the problems I might run into when trying to cluster 1000dimensional data compared to low dimensional data? After I plotted a distance histogram and discovered typical distance values, what should is the next step or where can I read up on the next step?

Comment: Don't use Euclidean distance in 1000 dimensions. Euclidean distance is good for low-dimensional data, but it doesn't have numerical contrast in high-dimensional data, making it increasingly hard to set thresholds (look up: "Curse of dimensionality"). Find an appropriate similarity measure for your data set first.